# Would call `firebaseUser.getIdToken(refresh: true);` every app start be a problem?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to fix the question I post [firestore rules request.auth.token.firebase.identities["phone"] not update on IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59590938/firestore-rules-request-auth-token-firebase-identitiesphone-not-update-on-io)
Currently fix by call `firebaseUser.getIdToken(refresh: true);` to make refresh update after phone verified and app started. 
Would call `firebaseUser.getIdToken(refresh: true);` every app start be a problem? I think maybe if bunch of users keep fetching ID Token with server will causing server overload or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't think it would be a problem, it's not really the best way to go about getting the most recent ID token.  If you just want to know the most recently fetched ID token, you can use [addIDTokenDidChangeListener()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#addidtokendidchangelistener_:) to receive any updates to the ID token whenever the Firebase SDK automatically refreshes it (every hour).

You typically only force a refresh token if you know the custom claims or other information in the ID token have changed on the server, and you need to reload those for use on the client.  If this is not your situation, you probably don't need to force a reload.